# best practice Laravel PageController

Tags: php, laravel, dynamic, static, controller

I was wondering if there is a best practice for static pages in one controller. I thought about a PageController that handles all the pages. What is the best practice to do this dynamically? The pages only contain some text and html.

Comment: Why serve them with a big PHP framework if they're static? Your webserver or a tiny session management PHP codebase is infinitely faster.

Comment: Do you want to do this with single controller and route?

Comment: Don't think there's a best practice here. There is nothing wrong with having a PagesController handling your static pages. If you are really lazy you could also return the view directly from your routes.

Comment: @loek only a few pages are static.

Comment: @waseemasgar That would be nice, that is exacly what I mean. Is there a best practice for that?

Comment: @Draity you could to something like this inside the routes file:

`Route::view('/about', 'pages.about');`

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is personal preference as to where you want to put them, in a big system I will put them within a controller where they are relevant eg. If I have a TasksController and I have a static tasks information page, that would be within the TasksController. If it is a forward facing part of the system I generally have a WebsiteController which deals with anything visible to the public.

Another potential way is to redirect on the route itself using something like :

`Route::view('/taskinfo', 'tasks.information');`

It's really a matter of what best works for you. I prefer the first option.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieved same on below code -

Route -

```
Route::get('/information/{id}','InformationController@show');
```

Controller Function -

```
public function show($id,Request $request)
{
  $data = array();
  $static_page_names =  ['static1','static2']; //array that contains all static pages name
  if(in_array($id, $static_page_names)){
    //static page code here 
    return view('/pages/static_page_template',$data);
  }else{
    //dynamic code here
    return view('/pages/dynamic_page_template',$data);
  }
}
```

You can access the page from browser like-

```
website-url/information/id or website/information/static-page-name
```

Might be it will helpfull to you